# Algorithm to compute maximum independent set of a chordal graph

Tags: graph-theory

1. If $G$ is perfect => $\omega(G) = \chi(G)$
2. Chordal graphs are perfect graphs

With an algorithm $A$ I can compute the perfect elimination ordering of a chordal graph $G$. I can extend $A$ in such way that it outputs the $\chi(G)$ ([maximal cliques and graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph#Maximal_cliques_and_graph_coloring)).

Also I know:

1. A graph $G$ is perfect <=> $\bar G$ is perfect

Can I conclude

If $\bar G$ is perfect => $\alpha(G) = \bar \chi(G)$

Because $\omega(G) = \chi(G) = \alpha(\bar G) = \bar \chi (\bar G)$ ?

If so than I can compute the maximal independent set $\alpha(G)$ with algorithm $A$ and $\bar G$ of the chordal graph $G$. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

> A graph G is perfect iif each induced subgraph has property $\alpha(G) = \chi(G)$. 
>   (see S. Krumke, H. Noltemeier: Graphentheoretische Konzepte und Algorithmen. p. 60)

More important is that $\bar G$ of a chordal graph is chordal too. I've found on wikipedia:

> Split graphs are graphs that are both chordal and the complements of chordal graphs (see [subclasses of chordal graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph#Subclasses))

That means that every complement graph of a chordal graph is a split graph which is also chordal.

But I found a disproof, you can see [the graphical representation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiSGS.png)
I switched the colored nodes for better showing the circle of length 4 which has no chord. Therefore the complement of a chordal graph is not always a chordal graph. The algorithm above will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The above argument fails because the complement of a chordal graph is not chordal. Hence you cannot use algorithm A to find the chromatic number of the complement graph, since algorithm A outputs the correct chromatic number only if the graph is chordal.

Comment: Might be helpful to answer the actual problem...